# How to merge multiple usages of C-d in Emacs into one

Tags: emacs

When I undo `C-d` in Emacs I can only restore one deleted letter at a time. This is extremely inconvenient. I would like all subsequent deletions to be treated as one for undelete purposes. Is there any way to control that? I found [undo-tree](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UndoTree) to be helpful, but this does not solve the problem as the undo tree gets extremely big when characters are deleted. The same goes for deletion using Backspace.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the way you delete things, use <kbd>C-u</kbd> to group multiple `delete-char` events into one undo.  You should also consider, where appropriate, other kill commands; `kill-word` <kbd>M-d</kbd>, `kill-sentence` <kbd>M-k</kbd>, `kill-region` <kbd>C-w</kbd>, etc.